# How to edit and update json data via html input fields?

Tags: javascript

- I am trying to update data via html input fields.
         I have 4 input fields where
         1st one is id, 
         2nd one text and 
         3rd and 4th blank input fields.

  ```
  3rd and 4th input should update data.
  ```

  Below is my json data and script

```
[
    {"id": 1, "testdata": "Exxon Mobil", "toBe_1": " ", "toBe_2": " " },

    {"id": 2, "testdata": "Wal-Mart Stores", "toBe_1": " ", "toBe_2": " "},

    {"id": 3, "testdata": "Royal Dutch Shell", "toBe_1": " ", "toBe_2": " "},

    {"id": 4, "testdata": "BP", "toBe_1": " ", "toBe_2": " " },

    {"id": 5, "testdata": "General Motors", "toBe_1": " ", "toBe_2": " " }
]
```

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var dataArray = [];
        data.forEach(function (d) {
          dataArray.push(d);
        });
        console.log(dataArray);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/dummyData.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    2
```

Comment: What's the `2` in your JS code doing?

Comment: post the code you have tried so far to update the field